# Java :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write a program for a simple calculator that just adds two numbers and shows it in a `JLabel`. I have managed to design a working Window, Button, etc. But if I click the Button the Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` - Error happens and I don´t know how to solve it.

Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Rechnerwin {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textFielda;
private JTextField textFieldb;
private JLabel label;
int A;
int B;
int C;
String a;
String b;
String c;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Rechnerwin window = new Rechnerwin();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

public Rechnerwin() {

    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textFielda = new JTextField();
    textFielda.setBounds(44, 41, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textFielda);
    textFielda.setColumns(10);

    textFieldb = new JTextField();
    textFieldb.setBounds(307, 41, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldb);
    textFieldb.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String a = textFielda.getText();
            String b = textFieldb.getText();
            int A = Integer.parseInt(a);
            int B = Integer.parseInt(b);
            int C = A + B;
            String c = Integer.toString(C);
            label.setText(c);
        }
    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(169, 85, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("a");
    label.setBounds(146, 184, 131, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you acknowledge that is was asked before and you know is has been? Why did you still ask it? Just read the previous answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: As i mentioned in my text I looked for solutions ,but coudn´t find anything ,that could help me.

Comment: Please run a debugger and indicate where the failure occurs and perhaps inspect your objects thoroughly while doing so, we need this information in order to provide a useful answer.  A stack trace would be nice, too.

Comment: Try to take a look at the question linked by @Michael and follow the instructions to obtain the stacktrace of your exception. This will be needed to provide further assistance...

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe as the linked question is more like a howto on obtaining the stacktrace information, but is of little help only for fixing a concrete `NullPointerException` as in this case.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of the referenced question.  The `label` variable is used at the end of the button's `actionPerformed`, but the global label was never initialized; only the locally-defined label was, a few lines later.  This is where the NullPointerException is coming from.  To confirm, comment out that line and re-run.  The error will be gone, but you won't have text in the label.  After you've confirmed this, you can uncomment the line again and fix the redundant variable names for `label`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving the label before the listener in the Button

## Example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("a");
label.setBounds(146, 184, 131, 20);
frame.getContentPane().add(label);

JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String a = textFielda.getText();
    String b = textFieldb.getText();
    int A = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int B = Integer.parseInt(b);
    int C = A + B;
    String c = Integer.toString(C);
    label.setText(c);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that in the listener you try to set the text for the member `label` of your `Rechnerwin` class. But this member is never initialized. After attaching the button listener you are adding a **new** JLabel to your UI with the same name as your member `label`. But these are two different variables and only the local one gets initialized.

You will probably solve this by this change:

```
...
label = new JLabel("a");
label.setBounds(146, 184, 131, 20);
...
```